# Use column-separator & (ampersand) inside \newenvironment

Tags: macros, tables, syntax, environments, ampersand

I'd like to define a *grammar* environment which basically wraps a *tabular* environment. Inside the *grammar* environment I'd like to use an environment called *production* to insert rows. Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\newenvironment{production}[1]
{\noindent\ignorespaces#1 ::= &}
{\\}

\newenvironment{grammar}
{\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}l}}
{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}
\begin{production}{XmlStartTag}
  ...
\end{production}
\begin{production}{XmlEndTag}
  ...
\end{production}
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

The goal of this code is to put the name of the non-terminal that is being defined in the left column and the actual production into the right column of the tabular.

Unfortunately this fails due to the `&` and `\\` within the *production* environment. I guess it has something to do with macro expansion. I guess I have to escape the `&` and `\\` with something that is only expanded after the macro was used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` pair commands automatically create a "group" so that, in effect, the `&` and `\\` are "out of scope" for the tabular, while inside the "production" environment they just show up at a place where the compiler is not expecting them.

A second problem with your definitions is that, even if they would work, they would be adding an extra `\\` at the end of the tabular, adding an unwanted space at the end. Perhaps some more appropriate definitions would be

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\production}[1]{#1 ::= &}
\newenvironment{grammar}{\tabular{p{3cm}l}}{\endtabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}
\production{XmlStartTag} ... \\
\production{XmlOtherTag} ... \\
\production{XmlEndTag} ...
\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

Note no `\\` at the end of the last production. Also in the definition of the `grammar` you don't need to repeat the work of `\begin`/`\end`, and you can instead directly use `\tabular` and `\endtabular`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the newline hint! It works as Ulrike Fischer and you propose (using a command). However, I still wonder if there would be an *easy* way to make it work with an environment. Using an environment I would have more ways to change the formatting of the entire production as one unit.

Comment: No, not an easy way. At least not if you continue to use a tabular around. Can't you do without the tabular and use inside the production environment \parbox, \makebox, minipage, lrbox etc? You could also look at the eqparbox-package.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: The answer was completely wrong; sorry to those who had upvoted.

I found a trick when trying to solve [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7769/). You can use the `environ` package and define the `production` environment as follows:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{production}[1]{%
  \toks0={\noindent\ignorespaces#1 ::= &}%
  \toks2=\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \toks4={\\}%
  \xdef\gtemp{\the\toks0 \the\toks2 \the\toks4 }%
  \aftergroup\gtemp
}
```

`\BODY` is the content of the environment.  The code works as follows: store `\noindent\ignorespaces#1 ::= &` into the token register `\toks0`, then store `\BODY` (expanded by `\expandafter`) into `\toks2`, and the trailing code `\\` into `\toks4`.  Put everything together into the global token list `\gtemp`.  The `\xdef` expands `\the\toks0`, `\the\toks2`, and `\the\toks4` (spaces after the numbers are important).  Finally, `\aftergroup\gtemp` places the `\gtemp` after the end of the group formed by `\begin{production}...\end{production}`, so that this group does not interfere with groups produced by the tabular. See the answer to [the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7769/) I mention above.

Two questions for more experienced TeXers: can I use `\unexpanded` to do this better? Is there a good way of executing a lot of stuff `\aftergroup`: I hate having to define `\gtemp` globally.

Comment: I get the error `undefined control sequence (\end{production} ...)`. Everything works if I delete the ampersand. Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Thank you very much @Dominik.  My code was simply wrong, now fixed.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Concerning your question: You could do `\toks2=\expandafter{\BODY}\xdef\gtemp{\unexpanded{\noindent\ignorespaces#1 ::= &} \the\toks2 \unexpanded{\\}}`, because you don't expand the contents of `\toks0` and `\toks4` anyway. For `\\` a simple `\noexpand` would also suffice because it is a single token. Regarding the `\aftergroup` and global dilemma: The problem is that `\aftergroup` only takes a single token. You could in principle put together all tokens and then iterate over them appending them to the `\aftergroup` register. This is just much more tedious than a global macro.

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with macro expansion but with grouping: Cells in a tabular build a group. You are starting an environment in one group and close it in the next. Use better a command \production.

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented Bruno Le Floch's answer with `expl3`. There it is easier to expand a token list only once.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{environ,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron { production } [1]
 {
  \tl_gclear:N \g_tmpa_tl
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_tl { \noindent\ignorespaces#1 ~ ::= & }
  \tl_gput_right:No \g_tmpa_tl { \BODY }
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_tmpa_tl { \\ }
  \group_insert_after:N \g_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newenvironment{grammar}
{\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}l}}
{\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
  \begin{production}{XmlStartTag}
    ...
  \end{production}
  \begin{production}{XmlEndTag}
    ...
  \end{production}
\end{grammar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose having separate *prod1* and *prodn* production commands would allow \\ to be automatically inserted: make *prodn* prepend \\.