# Can this command be converted to environment?

Tags: tables, environments, macros

I have a command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{&&&#1\tabularnewline\hline}
```

And now I want to convert it to be an environment as follows:

```
\newsavebox{\tempDescription}
\newenvironment{Description}
{%
\begin{lrbox}{\tempDescription}%
\ignorespaces%
}
{%
\end{tempDescription}%
&&&\usebox{\tempDescription}\tabularnewline\hline%
}
```

---

The complete code is given below:

```
\documentclass[dvips,dvipsnames,rgb,table]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=10mm,vmargin=40mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\newcounter{No}
\renewcommand{\theNo}{\arabic{No}}
\newenvironment{MyTable}[4]%
{%
    \newcolumntype{O}[1]%
    {%
        >{%
            \begin{minipage}%
            {%
                    ##1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth%
            }%
            \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
         }%
        c%
        <{%
                \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
                \end{minipage}%
         }%
    }%
    \newcolumntype{I}[1]%
    {%
        >{%
            \begin{minipage}%
            {%
                    ##1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth%
            }%
            \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
         }%
        c%
        <{%
                \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
                \end{minipage}%
         }%
    }%
    \setcounter{No}{0}%comment out this if you want to continuous numbering for all tables.
    \begin{longtable}%
    {%
            |>{\stepcounter{No}\centering\scriptsize\theNo}O{#1}<{}%
            |>{\centering}I{#2}<{\input{\jobname.tmp}}%
            |>{\centering\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}I{#3}<{}%
            |>{\scriptsize}O{#4}<{}%
            |%
    }%
    \hline\ignorespaces%
}%
{%
    \end{longtable}%
}

\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{&&&#1\tabularnewline\hline}

\newsavebox{\tempDescription}
\newenvironment{Description}
{%
\begin{lrbox}{\tempDescription}%
\ignorespaces%
}
{%
\end{tempDescription}%
&&&\usebox{\tempDescription}\tabularnewline\hline%
}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
language={PSTricks},
breaklines=true,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,%
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30}%
}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\def\MyRow{%        
        \VerbatimEnvironment%
        \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}%
}

\def\endMyRow{%
        \end{VerbatimOut}%      
}



\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{%
gridwidth=0.4pt,%default: 0.8pt
gridcolor=Red!20,%default: black
griddots=0,%default: 0 
%
gridlabels=3pt,%default: 10pt
gridlabelcolor=Blue,%default: black
%
subgriddiv=5,%default: 5
subgridwidth=0.2pt,%default: 0.4pt
subgridcolor=Green!20,%default: gray
subgriddots=0%default: 0
}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
%\clearpage
%\pagestyle{empty}
%Landscape starts here.
%\begin{landscape}
\arrayrulecolor{Red}
\begin{MyTable}{0.05}{0.3}{0.3}{0.35}%
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture*[showgrid](3,3)
\pnode(1,1){A}
\pnode(3,3){B}
\ncline{A}{B}
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[1]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=red!30](3,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[2]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=green!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[3]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=Yellow](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{%
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
\end{equation}
is the fundamental theorem of calculus.
}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](3,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=Maroon!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\begin{Description}%{%
Today I ate burnt bread. It was so delicious.
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
\end{equation}
is the fundamental theorem of calculus.
%}
\end{Description}
%=============
\end{MyTable}
%\end{landscape}
%Landscape stops here.
%\pagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Why cannot it be converted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Description}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\gtemp\expandafter{%
    \expandafter&\expandafter&\expandafter&\BODY\tabularnewline\hline
  }%
  \aftergroup\gtemp
}
```

It does not allow verbatim text, but the package `cprotect` can fix that. My first attempt accepted verbatim directly, but using lrbox only allows one-line boxes (not quite true).

We use Will Robertson's `environ` package to define the `Description` environment. It reads the whole content of the environment (until reaching `\end{Description}`) and stores it in `\BODY`. Naively, we would want

```
\NewEnviron{Description}{%
  &&&\BODY\tabularnewline\hline}
```

But this fails: `&&&\BODY\tabularnewline\hline` is created inside a group, and the whole thing behaves somewhat like `{&&&\BODY...}` rather than `&&&\BODY...`. We want to get the `&` out of the group. This is done using the `\aftergroup` primitive: `{...\aftergroup\a}` gives `{...}\a`, i.e., `\a` is executed after the group is finished.

So, we store what we want to do after inside a command, `\gtemp`, and do `\aftergroup\gtemp`. You would thus think that the correct code is

```
\NewEnviron{Description}{%
  \gdef\gtemp{%
    &&&\BODY\tabularnewline\hline
  }%
  \aftergroup\gtemp
}
```

But it is *not* the end yet. `\BODY` is only the body of our environment while we are inside the group. When we try executing `&&&\BODY\tabularnewline\hline` outside the group, we get an error: `\BODY` is not defined. What should we do? We need to replace `\BODY` by its *expansion* (definition) while we are still inside the group. For this use `\expandafter`, which is quite practical, but messy to use. It tells TeX "see the next token? well... wait, do (expand) the next one first". A typical construction is `\expandafter\a\expandafter\b\expandafter\c\expandafter\d\e`. The first `\expandafter` reads `\a`, and expands the next token, `\expandafter`. This second `\expandafter` sees `\b`, but starts by expanding `\expandafter`, etc. In the end, `\e` is expanded first, and then `\a`, `\b`, `\c`, `\d`. (The various tokens don't get re-ordered: only the way they are expanded changes.)

So in our final code, which I repeat here,

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Description}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\gtemp\expandafter{%
    \expandafter&\expandafter&\expandafter&\BODY\tabularnewline\hline
  }%
  \aftergroup\gtemp
}
```

we first expand `\BODY`, and then `\gdef\gtemp{&&&`*body*`\tabularnewline\hline}`, where *body* is the real content of the environment (`\BODY` expanded). Finally, the `\aftergroup\gtemp` explained above will put this at the right place in the flow of the tabular.

Comment: @Bruno, do we need `\ignorespaces` in your solution?

Comment: @xport: I must admit that I have no idea :(... Try with or without (remember to put `\expandafter` in front of everything before `\BODY`).

Comment: @Bruno, I think we don't need `ignorespaces` anymore because the package author already used it internally.

Comment: @xport:w Ok. Someday I'll learn about spacing in environments (recently I was mostly fighting with verbatim-like things).

Answer (score 9):

What you are doing doesn't work because of the way TeX parses arguments to go into an alignment (which is the technology underlying tables). When deciding what goes into a table cell, TeX reads one token with macro expansion on, checks it for special cases like `\span`, then it scans the text without macro expansion on up to the next `&` or `\cr` token. What it finds goes into a table cell, and is then processed the usual way, with macro expansion and all.

Your problem is that `\begin{Description}` does all sorts of setup before it gets around to executing `\Description`, and in particular `\Description` does not get expanded before TeX hits the first nonexpandable token resulting from expanding `\begin`. So TeX does not see the `&` tokens in there, and assumes it all goes into a single table cell.