# Cannot create an environment for a table cell

Tags: tables, environments

I have an environment whose behavior depends some outer circumstances. In some cases, the environment should act as a table cell (and in other cases it should act as a paragraph). The appropriate `\begin{tabular}{...}` and `\end{tabular}` are printed by another macros, which also change their behavior appropriately.

However, I can't define the appropriate environment. The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{cell}{}{&}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\begin{cell}
    abc
\end{cell}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The `&` has to be *actually seen* by the tabular, and not merely produced by some intermediate macro/environment.  Thus, you would need `\newenvironment{cell}{}{}` and `\begin{tabular}{lll}
\begin{cell}
    abc
\end{cell}&&
\end{tabular}`

Comment: basically you can either not use an environment for the cell, or not use `\halign`/`tabular` and make your environment produce boxes of known size that you can stack to make an alignment

Answer (score 0):

Using this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8084/168600
I've found a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{cell}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\gtemp\expandafter{%
    \BODY\expandafter&
  }%
  \aftergroup\gtemp
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l}
\begin{cell}
    abc
\end{cell}
\begin{cell}
    def
\end{cell}

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```