# \aftergroup a list of tokens

Tags: tex-core, expansion

`\aftergroup` executes the next token after the end of the current group. Is there a variant, `\Vaftergroup{\some\tokens\a\b}` that would put `\some\tokens\a\b` after the current group ends? Of course, one can do `\aftergroup\some\aftergroup\tokens\aftergroup\a\aftergroup\b`, but when the list is longer, it becomes messy.

This is motivated by [an answer that works but is ugly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3108/use-column-separator-ampersand-inside-newenvironment/8119#8119).

Comment: mark wooding's doafter package was designed after he had asked this question some time in the 80s.  it's conceivable he did it without benefit of etex (which would have been very new at the time, if it existed at all)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In much the same vein as Herbert's answer, a 'pre-built' version of the same idea is provided by the [`etextools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etextools) package: see `\AfterGroup`. I guess that `\aftergroup` is used rarely enough that this has not been a big demand :-)

Comment: studying this package will teach me much about the fine points of expansion, I believe :). Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Bruno ...or else drive you mad `:)`

Comment: The `\AfterGroup` macro solves the problem in the way outlined by Herbert, but defining a new global temporary macro each time (via a counter) which is then undefined at use time.

Answer (score 11):

don't know if this might help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ta{Hello}
\def\tb{ World. }
\def\tc{How are you?}
%\def\Tokens{\ta\tb\tc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\gdef\Tokens{\ta\tb\tc}% or like above with def
\aftergroup\Tokens
\let\ua=\tc
\let\ub=\tb
\let\uc=\ta
\ua\ub\uc---\par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing, but I didn't like the idea of a global temporary variable: bad things can happen before the group is finished.

Answer (score 7):

Put this in your preamble

```
% Usage
% \Aftergroup{ balanced text }
% \Aftergroup token text token 
%                    where text is any row of tokens and token is a character that is not in text (compare \verb)
%
% Example:
% \Aftergroup {\aaa{bbb}} and \Aftergroup @\aaa{bbb}@ put \aaa{bbb} after the endgroup
% whereas \Aftergroup }\aaa{bbb}} and \Aftergroup \egroup\aaa{bbb}} put \aaa{bbb after the second "}"
%
% For the unbalanced text a problem is that we can not distinguish "{" and "\bgroup" (or 
% "}"and "\egroup". Hence by
% Aftergroup @\bgroup \egroup@ the tokens inserted after the group are "{}" and by
% Aftergroup \bgroup \egroup @\bgroup the tokens "}@ are put after the group.  

\makeatletter

\def\Aftergroup{\bgroup
    \let\Bgroup={\let\bgroup}%give \bgroup a different meaning, } to balance
    \@ifnextchar\Bgroup
        {\egroup\@AGBalancedText}
        {\@ifnextchar\egroup
            {\egroup\def\@AGdelimiter{\egroup}\afterassignment\@AGDelNextToken\let\@let@token=}
            {\egroup\@AGDelimited}}
}

\def\@AGDelimited#1{\def\@AGdelimiter{#1}\@AGDelNextToken}

\def\@AGDelNextToken{%
    \expandafter\@ifnextchar\@AGdelimiter{\let\@let@token=}%end
       {\@ifnextchar\bgroup
        {\aftergroup{\iffalse}\fi\afterassignment\@AGDelNextToken\let\@let@token=}
        {\@ifnextchar\egroup
            {\iffalse{\fi\aftergroup}\afterassignment\@AGDelNextToken\let\@let@token=}
            {\@AGDeltoken}
}}}

\def\@AGDeltoken#1{\aftergroup#1\@AGDelNextToken}

\def\@AGBalancedText#1{\@AGBalNextToken#1{\@AGBalNextToken}}

\def\@AGBalNextToken#1#{\@AGBalNotOpen#1\@AGBalNotOpen\@AGBalClose}

\def\@AGBalNotOpen#1{\ifx\@AGBalNotOpen#1\else\aftergroup#1\expandafter\@AGBalNotOpen\fi}

\def\@AGBalClose#1{%
    \ifx\@AGBalNextToken#1\relax%
    \else\ifx\@AGBalClose#1\relax\iffalse{\else\aftergroup}\fi
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@AGBalNextToken%
        \else\iftrue\aftergroup{\else}\fi\@AGBalNextToken#1{\@AGBalClose}%
        \fi
    \fi
}

\makeatother
```

The following code

```
{\Aftergroup }\def\aaa{123}}\relax}\show\aaa
{\Aftergroup {\def\aaa{123\bgroup\egroup}}}\show\aaa
{\Aftergroup @\def\aaa{123\bgroup\egroup}@}\show\aaa
```

then gives

```
 > \aaa=macro:
 ->123\relax .
 l.102 {\Aftergroup }\def\aaa{123}}\relax}\show\aaa

 ? 
 > \aaa=macro:
 ->123\bgroup \egroup .
 l.103 ...p {\def\aaa{123\bgroup\egroup}}}\show\aaa

 ? 
 >\aaa=macro:
 ->123{}.
 l.104 ...p @\def\aaa{123\bgroup\egroup}@}\show\aaa
```

in the output window of TeX.

Answer (score 1):

Below there is an alternative. `\Tokens` remains local.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ta{Hello}
\def\tb{ World. }
\def\tc{How are you?}
%\def\Tokens{\ta\tb\tc}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\Tokens{\ta\tb\tc}% or like above with def
\let\ua=\tc
\let\ub=\tb
\let\uc=\ta
\ua\ub\uc---\par
\expandafter\endgroup\Tokens

\show\Tokens
\end{document}
```

Comment: This requires that you 'know' where the end-of-group is (and is going to be tricky to pull off in box/`\halign` contexts). Herbert's answer is 'general' in the sense you don't need to know where or how the group is going  to end.