# \expandafter and \aftergroup: where do the 2n+1 and n^2-1 rules come from?

Tags: tex-core, expansion

Both TeX primitives `\expandafter` and `\aftergroup` have "rules of thumb" stating that

1. `\expandafter` should be used `2n+1` times to look `n` tokens ahead (is this correct?).
2. A similar "rule of thumb" holds for `\aftergroup` assignments: `n^2-1`.

**Could anybody break down where these rules come from?** I understand the basic idea of expanding a token to its definition, but I'm failing to generalize this to an arbitrary lookahead, that is, an expansion of the token `n` tokens ahead is still difficult for me.

PS: I've included an "aftergroup" tag, since I wasn't sure what tag would fit the best. Feel free to adjust if you think you know how to tag it correctly.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7703 perhaps?

Comment: @JosephWright Good start. ;-) Should I change my question to only cover `\aftergroup` then?

Comment: We certainly have fewer questions on `\aftergroup`, though I note for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8136. Probably a more focussed question is not a dupe.

Comment: as explained in the "almost duplicate" answer, `\expandafter` normally accumulates in groups of 2^n-1 rather than 2n+1. For `\aftergroup` (if you edit the question just to ask about that) it depends whether you are trying to place n tokens after the current group, or lift one token out of n nested group levels.

Comment: I extended my answer to show examples of `\aftergroup` that are not in groups of 2^n-1.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`\expandafter` is covered elsewhere so I'll restrict to `\aftergroup`.

Consider the plain tex file

```
{{{
xxx
\aftergroup a
xxx
\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup b
xxx
\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup c
xxx }
yyy }
zzz }

\bye
```

this produces

[image]

`\aftergroup` takes the following token out of the input stream and re-inserts it after the group ends.

So `\aftergroup a` inserts `a` after the first `}`

To understand the three `\aftergroup` before `b` consider them line by line as shown.

`\aftergroup\aftergroup` the first `\aftergroup` executes and places the (unexecuted) `\aftergroup` token at the end of the group (in this case it will be inserted after the `a` which had been previously placed in the `\aftergroup` queue.

`\aftergroup b` places `b` at the end of the current group, it will be inserted after the `\aftergroup` just discussed.

This means that at the first `}` the tokens `a\aftergroup b` are inserted, so `a` is typeset then `\aftergroup` removes `b` again and re-inserts it when the next `}` is encountered.

The seven `\aftergroup` before `c` are similar. Initially reading line you find that
every other token is inserted after the current group, so after `b` the tokens
`\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup c` are inserted which as just discussed inserts
`\aftergroup c` after that group, so finally at the last `}` c is inserted and gets typeset.

So as to lift a token one extra group level you need to aftergroup all the `\aftergroup` tokens used at the previous level, plus an `\aftergroup` on the token of interest, you find that you usually have 1,3,7,...2^n-1 `\aftergroup` tokens to lift a token through n group levels.

---

Note that it isn't a rule that there has to be 2^n-1 `\aftergroup` interesting effects can be obtained by other groupings:

```
{{{
xxx
\aftergroup\aftergroup a
yyy}zzz
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup b
www}qqq}mmm

\bye
```

produces

[image]

Here `\aftergroup\aftergroup` places `\aftergroup` after the first `}`; the `a` is not affected at all, so typesets as normal after `xxx`. Then at the `}` the `\aftergroup`
token is inserted and applies to the first `z` so only two `zz` get typeset at that point, the first `z` is typeset at the next `}` after `www`.

The four `\aftergroup` before `b` are similar. Two `\aftergroup` tokens are removed and inserted at the next `}` and `b` is not affected at all, so typesets after the `zz`.
the two `\aftergroup` are inserted at the next `}` so the input is

```
\aftergroup\aftergroup qqq}mmm
```

this inserts an `\aftergroup` after the `}` so is equivalent to

```
qqq}\aftergroup mmm
```

so one `m` is taken out of the input and two `mm` are typeset. The first `m` just silently vanishes as it would appear at the end of the current group but this is the top level so it is just lost (not an error).

Answer (score 22):

The (unexpandable) primitive `\aftergroup` applies to the next token only; it makes TeX save the token in a FIFO list that will be delivered as soon as the current group ends. So

```
\begingroup\aftergroup x\aftergroup y\endgroup
```

is just the same as typing `xy`: the list is “first in, first out”. Note that in case of a macro, TeX only saves the macro, not its meaning. Thus

```
\def\foo{X}
\begingroup\def\foo{Y}\aftergroup\foo\endgroup
```

will print `X`, because the redefinition of `\foo` disappears as soon as `\endgroup` is executed.

It doesn't matter what group we're in; it can be any of the sixteen different group types. For instance, `\hbox{A\aftergroup B}` will box an `A` and print `B` outside the box; the first example could have been `{\aftergroup x\aftergroup y}`.

Leaving aside problems due to the limited size reserved for the FIFO list, what tokens can follow `\aftergroup`? Any token, even `{` or `}`; the definition of the LaTeX environment `lrbox` is very instructive in this respect.

If you want to chain tokens in order to reappear after the current group has ended, just precede each one by `\aftergroup`:

```
\begingroup\aftergroup\mbox\aftergroup{\aftergroup X\aftergroup}\endgroup
```

will make TeX see the tokens `\mbox{X}` just after the group has ended (and all settings are restored).

Note that `\aftergroup{\mbox{X}}` is ***not*** equivalent to the code above: `\aftergroup` does not accept arguments in braces, *it only applies to the token that immediately follows it*.

If you want to defer code when *two* groups end, it's easy:

```
\begingroup\begingroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\foo
\endgroup\endgroup
```

The meaning should be clear: when the current group (at nesting level 2) ends, TeX will deliver `\aftergroup\foo`, which will save back `\foo` in the aftergroup list for deliver after the outer group ends. Any group level has its own incarnation of this list.

If you want to climb three levels, just remember that each group consumes one `\aftergroup`: so

```
\begingroup\begingroup\begingroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\foo
\endgroup\endgroup\endgroup
```

will do, because when the level 3 group ends, the list will contain

```
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\foo
```

Do yourself the proof by induction that, in order to climb up *n* levels, you need 2<sup>*n*</sup> - 1 `\aftergroup` tokens before `\foo`.