# Underline a page head

Tags: header-footer, rules

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ps@headings{
  \def\@evenhead{foo bar}
  \def\@oddhead{foo bar}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\section{Introduction}
foo bar baz

\end{document}
```

(This is just an example. The real document is a bit more complicated...)

How can I have a rule below the »foo bar« header?

I'd like to get something like this:

[image: header with horizontal rule]

That is: a rule size `\hsize`. I don't want to use `fancyhdr`.

Edit: More requirements: I need to configure the rule thickness and the distance between the words »foo ... bar« and the horizontal rule.

Comment: Would you consider using `titleps`(a sibling of `titlesec`)?

Comment: @Bernard no... The problem is, that I have a medium complex document class with already predefined headers and footers. I don't want to add another layer of complexity on top of it, so I wanted to have a solution based on the LaTeX's commands for headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `\myhrule` for rules in headers looks slight different than David's. The position of the heading text doesn't depend on the depth of the text. And, of course, I needn't any additional package.

```
\makeatletter
\def\myhrule{\lower1ex\null\vadjust{\hrule}}
\renewcommand\ps@headings{%
  \def\@evenhead{foo\hfill bar\myhrule}%
  \def\@oddhead{foo\hfill bar\myhrule}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: yes this is a nice alternative in the in the non-color case. In color it fails for same reason mine did (there is an extra `\hbox{{` ...`}}` around the heading to constrain colour specials) Although given this information you should be able to fix:-) (see my not so pretty edited answer)

Comment: Yes, the usage is simple in plain TeX: `\headline={\myhrule foo\hfil bar}`, but LaTeX brings complications (as usual:). When color LaTeX package is loaded then `\aftergroup\myhrule` works. Note: only *one* `\aftergroup`.

Comment: That's cool. I don't understand it yet, but less `\aftergroup`s than David's solutions

Comment: @wipet David told me that your answer is better than his answer, but he also told me that I should not tell you. So ignore my comment from now and accept the fact that some uniDentified Person Came here and suggested me to use your answer.

Comment: @topskip: I see what you did there. `:)` I think we could agree that DPC = Donald P. Cnuth. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda who else should that be :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just under line them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ps@headings{
  \def\@evenhead{\uline{foo bar}}
  \def\@oddhead{\uline{foo bar}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\section{Introduction}
foo bar baz
\clearpage
\section{Introduction}
foo bar baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the thickness and depth of the rule by

```
\setlength{\ULdepth}{2ex}
\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{2pt}
```

Same with `soul`:

```
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ps@headings{%
  \def\@evenhead{\ul{foo bar}}%
  \def\@oddhead{\ul{foo bar}}%
}
\makeatother
```

The depth and thickness can be changed by

```
\setul{2ex}{2pt}
```

Sorry about the bad boxes. I am not responsible :-)

Comment: Looks great, thanks. This reminds me that I have more requirements. See the edit of the question (sorry about that).

Comment: Perfect thanks!! I chose the ulem way, works nicely.

Comment: @topskip I have added `\setul{2ex}{2pt}` for `soul` too. :)

Comment: Bad boxes are here because between foo and bar isn't infinitely stretchable glue, only normal space is here. You need to declare `\def\@evenhead{\uline{foo\hfil bar}}` but `soul` package doesn't work with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add a rule after the box that holds the heading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\myhrule{\vskip1ex\hrule height 5pt}
\renewcommand\ps@headings{%
  \def\@evenhead{foo\hfill bar\aftergroup\myhrule}%
  \def\@oddhead{foo\hfill bar\aftergroup\myhrule}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\section{Introduction}
foo bar baz

\end{document}
```

Or if you have `color` loaded

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\def\myhrule{\vskip1ex\hrule height 5pt}
\renewcommand\ps@headings{%
  \def\@evenhead{foo\hfill bar\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\myhrule}
  \def\@oddhead{foo\hfill bar\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup
\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\myhrule}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}

\section{Introduction}
foo bar baz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks much better, but it doesn't work with my real document.... `! Missing \endgroup inserted. <inserted text>  \endgroup `. I am not too keen on reducing the problem right now.

Comment: @topskip fixed (My earlier self added extra groups to latex's heading code to control colour specials so my current self added a few extra `\aftergroup` to escape)

Comment: @topskip see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232003/1090

Comment: OK, trivial then. I understand ;) (No, I think I understand why the many `\aftergroup`, but I would not have found out about the extra group the color package adds).