# Formatting phonenumbers with phonenumber-package and macros as argument (expand-problem)

Tags: macros, expansion, arguments

I try to use the `phonenumbers`-package to format phonenumbers. As argument I want to use a macro (in the actual document the macro will be defined with `pgfkeys`!)

What I tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[area-code-sep=hyphen, country=DE]{phonenumbers}

\begin{document}
\def\tel{01601234567}

\noindent
\phonenumber{01601234567}\\                                 % Correct!
\phonenumber{\tel}\\                                        % No Output
\expandafter\phonenumber{\tel}\\                            % No Output
\expandafter\phonenumber\tel\\                              % Unformatted
\expandafter\phonenumber\bgroup\tel\egroup\\                % Unformatted
\expandafter\phonenumber\expandafter\bgroup\tel\egroup\\    % Unformatted
\end{document}
```

I don't understand, how I can expand my `\tel`-macro before using it as an argument.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\expandafter\phonenumber\expandafter{\tel}
```

works in the example. You need the first `\expandafter` to 'jump over' `\phonenumber` and the second `\expandafter` to 'jump over' the `{`, so that `\tel` is expanded before `\phonenumber{` and you end up with `\phonenumber{01601234567}`.

In the example it is important that `\phonenumber` be passed the actual number and not just a macro containing the number. So we have to expand (unpack) the argument (once) before we use it.

If you use a different definition for `\tel` in your real-world document you may need more `\expandafter`s if it turns out the definition uses more "layers".
If you additionally have `\def\telA{\tel}`, one `\expandafter` is not enough, you will need three on each side of `\phonenumber`, because you now need to expand `\telA` twice to get to the number. For three levels of expansion you would need seven. See [\expandafter and \aftergroup: where do the 2n+1 and n^2-1 rules come from?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231996/35864).

If you are sure that your macros expand to a number if you just keep expanding them until that is not possible any more, you can use a different approach that saves you a lot of `\expandafters` in situations where several expansion steps are required. Just expand the argument completely. You can use `\edef` and `\noexpand` (see [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451/35864)) or the `\romannumeral` trick (https://www.texdev.net/2011/07/05/expansion-using-romannumeral/). The differences betwen `\edef` and `\romannumeral` become important when your macro consists of several elements, `\romannumeral` will only go on expanding the first token as far as possible, `\edef` will expand everything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[area-code-sep=hyphen, country=DE]{phonenumbers}

\def\tel{01601234567}
\def\telA{\tel}
\def\telB{\telA}

\def\telp{0160}
\def\telq{1234567}
\def\telpA{\telp\telq}
\def\telpB{\telpA}

\def\myphonenumber#1{\phonenumber{#1}\quad(\texttt{\detokenize{#1}})}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\myphonenumber{01601234567}

\item % does not work, \tel is not a number
\myphonenumber{\tel}

\item
\expandafter\myphonenumber\expandafter{\tel}

\item % does not work, \telA needs two expansion steps to get a number
\expandafter\myphonenumber\expandafter{\telA}

\item
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\myphonenumber
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\telA}

\item
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\myphonenumber
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
{\telB}

\item
\begingroup
\edef\temp{\endgroup
  \noexpand\myphonenumber{\tel}}
\temp

\item
\begingroup
\edef\temp{\endgroup
  \noexpand\myphonenumber{\telA}}
\temp

\item
\begingroup
\edef\temp{\endgroup
  \noexpand\myphonenumber{\telB}}
\temp

\item 
\expandafter\myphonenumber\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\tel}

\item
\expandafter\myphonenumber\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\telA}

\item
\expandafter\myphonenumber\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\telB}

\item
\begingroup
\edef\temp{\endgroup
  \noexpand\myphonenumber{\telpB}}
\temp

\item
\expandafter\myphonenumber\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0\telpB}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

`{` and `\bgroup` and `}` and `\egroup` are not equivalent as argument delimiters. That's why `\expandafter\phonenumber\expandafter\bgroup\tel\egroup` did not work correctly. You can see what happens when you use `\bgroup`/`\egroup` instead of `{`/`}` in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\foo#1{-\detokenize{#1}-}

\begin{document}
\foo{DEF}

\foo\bgroup ABC\egroup
\end{document}
```

The first line works as expected and shows "-DEF-", but the second line throws an error about too many `}`s and shows "-`\bgroup`-ABC", this demonstrates that `\foo` assumes `\bgroup` is its argument and not the entire string `ABC`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd define `\phonenumber`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[area-code-sep=hyphen, country=DE]{phonenumbers}

\newcommand\tel{01601234567}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand \phonenumber {O{}mo}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn {phonenumbers} {#1}
  \IfNoValueTF { #3 }
   { \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:f { #2 } }
   { \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:ff { #2 } { #3 } }
  \phone_nummer_ausgeben:
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:nn
 {
  \phone_durchwahl_ueberpruefen:n {#2}
  \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:n {#1}
  \bool_lazy_or:nnF
   {\str_if_eq_p:Vn \l_phone_land_str {DE}}
   {\str_if_eq_p:Vn \l_phone_land_str {AT}}
   {
    \bool_if:NF \l_phone_durchwahl_leer_bool
     {
      \msg_warning:nn {phonenumbers} {illegal~extension}
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:n {f}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:nn {ff}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\phonenumber{01601234567}

\phonenumber{\tel}

\end{document}
```

I've first split up the big definition in the package, using `\NewDocumentCommand` for just sorting out the optional arguments and call internal functions. Here it's necessary to use `\RenewDocumentCommand`.

This way one needs less boolean checks and also better flexibility; for instance, just changing `\phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:n` into `\phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:f` allows to specify input for `\phonenumber` as a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[area-code-sep=hyphen, country=DE]{phonenumbers}

\newcommand\tel{01601234567}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand \phonenumber {O{}mo}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn {phonenumbers} {#1}
  \IfNoValueTF { #3 }
   { \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:f { #2 } }
   { \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
  \phone_nummer_ausgeben:
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:nn
 {
  \phone_durchwahl_ueberpruefen:n {#2}
  \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:f {#1} % <--- change :n to :f
  \bool_lazy_or:nnF
   {\str_if_eq_p:Vn \l_phone_land_str {DE}}
   {\str_if_eq_p:Vn \l_phone_land_str {AT}}
   {
    \bool_if:NF \l_phone_durchwahl_leer_bool
     {
      \msg_warning:nn {phonenumbers} {illegal~extension}
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \phone_nummer_ueberpruefen:n {f}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\phonenumber{01601234567}

\phonenumber{\tel}

\end{document}
```

[image]